# mod_wsgi Call to fopen() failed for 'path/wsgi.py apache ubuntu

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu

hi i try to deploy my django project `2.2v` on ubuntu apache server

when i run `cat /var/log/apache2/error.log` i get this error:

> [time] [wsgi:error] [pid 13224:tid 2323232] (13)Permission denied: [remote some number:number] mod_wsgi (pid=13323, process='django_app', application='django_project|'): Call to fopen() failed for '/root/project_name/project_name/wsgi.py'.

my wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'zettapc.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

This is my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/django_proj.conf` :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Alias /static /root/project_name/static
    <Directory /root/project_name/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /meida /root/project_name/meida
    <Directory /root/project_name/meida>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /root/project_name/zettapc>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /root/project_name/project_name/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/root/project_name python-home=/root/project_name/venv/
    WSGIProcessGroup django_app 

</VirtualHost>
```

and output of on my browser is :

> Internal Server Error

this the output of `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'`
[image]

and output of `ls -l /root/project_name/project_name/wsgi.py` is:

```
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root 177 time /root/project_name/project_name/wsgi.py
```

is there something i've missed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your wsgi file is owned by root and apache server runs as a non-root user.
You can check which user your apache servers runs as with `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'`
and which user owns your wsgi file with `ls -l /root/project_name/project_name/wsgi.py`

You best bet would be to move your project from the root folder to somwhere more appropriate (for example `/usr/`) and change it's owner using `chown -r <user>:<user> <folder>`

Alternatively run apache server as root but it's a really bad practice so don't do that.

edit:
It might also be that your wsgi server (gunicorn/uwsgi ?) runs as the wrong user, the same fix still does the trick.

Comment: i updated the question with running your commands , can you check again please

Comment: the first collumn of ps: `www-data` means your apache server is ran by a user called `www-data`, this user cannot access a file owned by root such as your wsgi.py.
Move your project to `/usr/` and change it's owner to `www-data`.
There are many variables such as your current user that i don't know so i can't give you the exact commands but trial and error will get your there.

Comment: isnt there a way to change it to the same as wsgi ran ?

Comment: What wsgi server are you using ? it should be one of those https://wsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/servers.html
and what user is it running as ?

Comment: mod_wsgi , i use default root user

Comment: Try to get mod_wsgi to run as www-data or (bad advice) run apache as root.

Comment: sorry but how to do it